# Transactions and asynchronous processing

Tags: spring, transactions, jms

Assume some spring bean has transactional method and it does two things:

- asynchronously send JMS messages
- updates DB

The problem is that when the message is consumed, the DB transaction sometimes not have committed, and handler failed to find in DB expected value.

The evident solution - is to send in transaction, but I use async send available on ActiveMQ to increase throughput. If I make send transactional, I forfeit asynchrocity and also risk getting OuOfMemory.

How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an XA-enabled transaction manager, and send the JMS message and do the update to the DB in the same, distributed transaction.

This doesn't change anything to asynchronicity: the send call will return before the receiver receives the message. But when it receives it, the transaction will be committed, and the receiver will find the updates in the database.

I don't see what OutOfMemoryErrors have to do with this.

Comment: I thought that messages will not be sent to broker until transaction committed in this case, so I was afraid of losing throughput and OOM as a result of many waiting messages, but it looks I was wrong and your suggestion will solve the problem.

Comment: The message will be sent to the broker when you send them (just as a JDBC statement is sent to the database when you execute it). But the broker doesn't send it to the receiver until the transaction commits (just as a JDBC statement is actually persisted forever when the transaction commits).